# Python: Why is my Click CLI not executing the desired functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have a function with click decorators. The entire purpose of the function is to add a CLI option to the work being done by the tq_oex_interchange class.

```
@click.command()
@click.option('-input_file', help='The input file to process')
@click.option('-output_file', help='The output file to create')
@click.option('-part_num_col', help='The column containing the part numbers')
@click.option('-summate_cols', help='The columns to summate')
def run(input_file, output_file, part_num_col, summate_cols):
    from re import split
    summate_cols = [int(i) for i in split(',', summate_cols)]
    part_num_col = int(part_num_col)
    teek = tq_oex_interchange()
    click.echo("Working...")
    teek.scan_file(input_file, output_file, part_num_col, summate_cols)
```

However, when i execute my script with the command

```
python tq_oex.py -input_file C:\Users\barnej78\Desktop\test_0.csv -output_file C:\Users\barnej78\Desktop\cmd.csv -part_num_col 3 -summate_cols 5,6
```

Nothing happens, not even the click echo is executed.

Additionally,

```
python tq_oex.py --help
```

Also doesn't do anything.

There is no error or exception output for any of these command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the entire script?

Answer (score 2):

Have you been able to successfully run the example code from here?

http://click.pocoo.org/5/

I'd start with that and make sure it works. Then write a test for it, using the Click test docs:

http://click.pocoo.org/5/testing/

That way when you start tweaking it, you can runs tests to see what breaks...

With Click applications, I often start simple, with one argument, and then add another to make sure it still works:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('input_file')
def run_files(input_file):
    click.echo(input_file)
```

Then add one option to this:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('input_file')
@click.option('--output_file', help='The output file to create')
def run_files(input_file, output_file):
    click.echo(input_file, output_file)
```

I like to set defaults as well, for debugging purposes:

```
def run_files(input_file='/path/to/input_file',
              output_file='/path/to/output_file'):
    click.echo(input_file, output_file)
```